# Test Templates against each other in CLIPS RULES

Tags: clips

How do I test if all variables in template equal variables in different templates or if they don't. Need to have different outcomes from each output.

Attaching my code below:

```
``;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;                                    ;
;   Sablony pre vstupy                       ;
;                                    ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(deftemplate mobily
(slot znacka (type SYMBOL))
(slot model (type STRING) )  
(slot rozlisenie (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values HD FULL_HD Q_HD))  
(slot SD_Karta (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values ano nie))
(slot interna_pamat (type INTEGER) (range 32 512))  
(slot operacny_system (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values iOS android ine))
(slot uhlopriecka (type FLOAT) (range 4.0 7.0))
(slot rozlisenie_fotoaparatu (type INTEGER) (range 4 128))
(slot kapacita_baterie (type INTEGER) (range 5 25)))

(deftemplate zakaznik
(slot znacka (type SYMBOL))
(slot model (type STRING))  
(slot rozlisenie (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values HD FULL_HD Q_HD))  
(slot SD_Karta (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values ano nie))
(slot interna_pamat (type INTEGER) (range 32 512))  
(slot operacny_system (type SYMBOL) (allowed-values iOS android ine))
(slot uhlopriecka (type FLOAT) (range 4.0 7.0))
(slot rozlisenie_fotoaparatu (type INTEGER) (range 4 128))
(slot kapacita_baterie (type INTEGER) (range 5 25)))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;                                    ;
;   Vstupy                               ;
;                                    ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(deffacts mobily_na_sklade
(mobily(znacka Motorola)(model "Defy")(rozlisenie HD)(SD_Karta ano)(interna_pamat 64)(operacny_system android)(uhlopriecka 6.5)(rozlisenie_fotoaparatu 60)(kapacita_baterie 20)) (mobily(znacka Samsung)(model "Galaxy")(rozlisenie FULL_HD)(SD_Karta ano)(interna_pamat 128)(operacny_system android)(uhlopriecka 6.5)(rozlisenie_fotoaparatu 32)(kapacita_baterie 25))
(mobily(znacka Iphone)(model "14")(rozlisenie FULL_HD)(SD_Karta nie)(interna_pamat 128)(operacny_system iOS)(uhlopriecka 6.1)(rozlisenie_fotoaparatu 12)(kapacita_baterie 25)) 
(mobily(znacka Iphone)(model "13")(rozlisenie Q_HD)(SD_Karta nie)(interna_pamat 128)(operacny_system iOS)(uhlopriecka 6.1)(rozlisenie_fotoaparatu 12)(kapacita_baterie 20)) 
(mobily(znacka Asus)(model "Zenfone")(rozlisenie HD)(SD_Karta ano)(interna_pamat 32)(operacny_system android)(uhlopriecka 5.9)(rozlisenie_fotoaparatu 64)(kapacita_baterie 14))
(mobily(znacka Samsung)(model "Galaxy")(rozlisenie Q_HD)(SD_Karta nie)(interna_pamat 128)(operacny_system android)(uhlopriecka 6.1)(rozlisenie_fotoaparatu 12)(kapacita_baterie 25))
(mobily(znacka Motorola)(model "Moto")(rozlisenie FULL_HD)(SD_Karta ano)(interna_pamat 32)(operacny_system android)(uhlopriecka 6.3)(rozlisenie_fotoaparatu 13)(kapacita_baterie 15))
(mobily(znacka Xiaomi)(model "Redmi")(rozlisenie HD)(SD_Karta ano)(interna_pamat 64)(operacny_system android)(uhlopriecka 6.5)(rozlisenie_fotoaparatu 108)(kapacita_baterie 16)) 
)

(defrule vypis_uvod
=>
(printout t "Vitajte v programe na vyber telefonu" crlf)
(printout t "Prosim vyberte vase specifikacie: " crlf))

(defrule osobne_hodnoty
=>
(printout t "Zadajte znacku" crlf)
(bind ?znacka(read))
(printout t "Zadajte model" crlf)
(bind ?model(read))
(printout t "Zadajte ci vas vybrany telefon podporuje SD Karty (ano/nie)" crlf)
(bind ?SD_Karta(read))
(printout t "Zadajte rozlisenie displeja (HD, FULL_HD, Q_HD)" crlf)
(bind ?rozlisenie(read))
(printout t "Zadajte velkost internej pamete (32 - 512)" crlf)
(bind ?interna_pamat(read))
(printout t "Zadajte uhlopriecku (4.0 - 7.0)" crlf)
(bind ?uhlopriecka(read))
(printout t "Zadajte operacny system(iOS, android, ine)" crlf)
(bind ?operacny_system(read))
(printout t "Zadajte rozlisenie_fotoaparatu (4 - 128)" crlf)
(bind ?rozlisenie_fotoaparatu(read))
(printout t "Zadajte kapacitu baterie v hodinach (5 - 25" crlf)
(bind ?kapacita_baterie(read))

(assert (zakaznik (znacka ?znacka)(model ?model)(rozlisenie ?rozlisenie)(SD_Karta ?SD_Karta)(interna_pamat ?interna_pamat)(operacny_system ?operacny_system) (uhlopriecka ?uhlopriecka) (rozlisenie_fotoaparatu ?rozlisenie_fotoaparatu)(kapacita_baterie ?kapacita_baterie))))

(defrule telefon_je_na_sklade
(and
(zakaznik (znacka ?znacka)(model ?model)(rozlisenie ?rozlisenie)(SD_Karta ?SD_Karta)(interna_pamat ?interna_pamat)(operacny_system ?operacny_system) (uhlopriecka ?uhlopriecka) (rozlisenie_fotoaparatu ?rozlisenie_fotoaparatu)(kapacita_baterie ?kapacita_baterie))
(mobily (znacka ?znacka)(model ?model)(rozlisenie ?rozlisenie)(SD_Karta ?SD_Karta)(interna_pamat ?interna_pamat)(operacny_system ?operacny_system) (uhlopriecka ?uhlopriecka) (rozlisenie_fotoaparatu ?rozlisenie_fotoaparatu)(kapacita_baterie ?kapacita_baterie)))

=>
(printout t "Telefon je na sklade:" ?znacka ?model crlf))

(defrule telefon_nie_je_na_sklade
(and
(zakaznik (znacka ?znacka)(model ?model)(rozlisenie ?rozlisenie)(SD_Karta ?SD_Karta)(interna_pamat ?interna_pamat)(operacny_system ?operacny_system) (uhlopriecka ?uhlopriecka) (rozlisenie_fotoaparatu ?rozlisenie_fotoaparatu)(kapacita_baterie ?kapacita_baterie))
(not(mobily (znacka ?znacka)(model ?model)(rozlisenie ?rozlisenie)(SD_Karta ?SD_Karta)(interna_pamat ?interna_pamat)(operacny_system ?operacny_system) (uhlopriecka ?uhlopriecka) (rozlisenie_fotoaparatu ?rozlisenie_fotoaparatu)(kapacita_baterie ?kapacita_baterie))))
=>
(printout t "Bohuzial zadany telefon nemame na sklade" crlf))

`
`
```

I tried using AND in the rules but when I did this only the last rule was implemented even if the variables were actually the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your rules work. You just need to use the exact values specified in your mobily facts including the same case for symbols/strings and the enclosing quotation marks if you are matching a string.

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Vitajte v programe na vyber telefonu
Prosim vyberte vase specifikacie: 
Zadajte znacku
Xiaomi
Zadajte model
"Redmi"
Zadajte ci vas vybrany telefon podporuje SD Karty (ano/nie)
ano
Zadajte rozlisenie displeja (HD, FULL_HD, Q_HD)
HD
Zadajte velkost internej pamete (32 - 512)
64
Zadajte uhlopriecku (4.0 - 7.0)
6.5
Zadajte operacny system(iOS, android, ine)
android
Zadajte rozlisenie_fotoaparatu (4 - 128)
108
Zadajte kapacitu baterie v hodinach (5 - 25
16
Telefon je na sklade:XiaomiRedmi
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Vitajte v programe na vyber telefonu
Prosim vyberte vase specifikacie: 
Zadajte znacku
Xiaomi
Zadajte model
"Redmi"
Zadajte ci vas vybrany telefon podporuje SD Karty (ano/nie)
ano
Zadajte rozlisenie displeja (HD, FULL_HD, Q_HD)
HD
Zadajte velkost internej pamete (32 - 512)
64
Zadajte uhlopriecku (4.0 - 7.0)
6.5
Zadajte operacny system(iOS, android, ine)
android
Zadajte rozlisenie_fotoaparatu (4 - 128)
108
Zadajte kapacitu baterie v hodinach (5 - 25
20
Bohuzial zadany telefon nemame na sklade
CLIPS>
```